# recognize debug mode in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

how to do something like that in eclipse for c

```
#ifdef _DEBUG printf("debug mode is on\n");
#elif printf("debug mode is off\n");
```

I googled it and found that I need to use #ifdeb, but unfortunately it didn't work
thanks in advance for any help

Comment: How did it not work - can you give some information

Comment: I received: ..\main.c:11:8: no macro name given in #ifdef directive
..\main.c:13:7: #if with no expression
Build error occurred, build is stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The #ifdef and #elif use the whole line as the condition so the printf s are being interpreted as part of the #if. You need to put the code on separate lines and use a #endif to close the #if

e.g.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG 
printf("debug mode is on\n");
#else
printf("debug mode is off\n");
#endif
```

Comment: do I need to include some special library for this macro definition?

Comment: @geek No this is not a macro definition - it is just your code formatted to run correctly - I suspect if you are still confused you need to state more detail in your question (e.g. what happens if you try this)

Comment: your code didn't work, but I tried this one,  #if _DEBUG
 printf("debug mode is on\n");
 #else
 printf("debug mode is off\n"); but when I run in debug mode I always receive that debug mode is off, how is it possible?
 #endif,

Comment: I received: ..\main.c:11:8: no macro name given in #ifdef directive ..\main.c:13:7: #if with no expression Build error occurred, build is stopped

Comment: pity, but anyway I receive that debug mode is off, :(, build configuration is set to debug mode, what can be wrong?

Comment: @geek that should be a separate question